# git alias not specified but data pushed to github

Tags: git

I'm new to github. I started with

```
git remote add origin URL
```

This linked my local files with the github account. I then did:

```
git push -u origin master
```

This copied my files to github

I then proceeded to make some changes to my .py file in the local repository and then saved it. I did this to test the commit + push feature. Next I typed:

```
git add.
git status
git commit -m "Q1 solution"
git push
```

The code pushed to github but I am not sure if I did it correctly. Youtube videos are all saying I should have done git push origin (the alias-ed URL). Do I need to do this or is git push enough once you've done the initial setup with:

```
git push -u origin master
```

Edit:
`git status`

gives me:

```
On branch master
Your branch is up to date with 'origin/master'.
```

Not sure what this means origin/master?!?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `-u` option to `git push` means:

> `-u`
> `--set-upstream`
>
> For every branch that is up to date or
> successfully pushed, add upstream (tracking) reference, used by
> argument-less git-pull and other commands.

So from that point on, running `git push` by itself is the same as running `git push origin master` -- in both cases, you are saying "push my `master` branch to the `master` branch of the remote named `origin`".

When you see the message:

```
Your branch is up to date with 'origin/master'.
```

This means you have already synchronized your local branch with the remote branch.

Comment: so basically because i typed: ```git push -u origin master``` the first time, every subsequent time I can just use ```git push```? If I didn't use the git -u what happens? Will it force me to type ```git push origin master``` every time?

Comment: After having set the tracking branch with `-u`, from that point on you can just use `git push` and it will push it to the appropriate upstream branch.

Comment: on github website it recommends this: …or push an existing repository from the command line
```git remote add origin URL,
git branch -M main,
 git push -u origin main``` 
 I didn't branch. Do you need to make a branch before you push the first time or is that optional?

Comment: You are already working on a branch named `master`. You can certainly create additional branches as necessary; that's the recommended practice when working on new features. There are lots of articles out there about branching and development workflows; that's too big a topic to cover in comments here.

Answer (score 1):

My friend
you pushed it correctly to the master branch

when we use :

```
git push
```

it's pushed automatically to the repo and into the branch where you are which is the master branch

when should I use the full hand version?

```
git push [alias] [branch]
git push origin main/master
```

we use this one when we want to push our changes to another branch

and you can

create a branch in git

```
git branch [name]
```

then you want to make changes in just this branch
you should stage it

```
git checkout [name of the branch]
```

and you can add or commit without changing anything in the other branches

check this cheat sheet
https://education.github.com/git-cheat-sheet-education.pdf

Comment: the whole ```origin``` thing is confusing. It could be any word right? Could I use: ```git remote add ilovepizza URL```, followed by ```git push -u ilovepizza master```? Would that work or is origin some kind of keyword in git? PS Thanks for the cheat sheet.

Comment: yeah it's an alias for your long URL

you can use whatever you like